# Apple Store and Play Store reports

Tags: r, google-play, itunes

I would like to know if its possible to get, via API, informations like AppStore Search, Browse, etc., of my app (the same on google play, algo installs, uninstalls).

I am using R to try to get these informations, but I might use other resources do to that, as long as I can do it automatically.

Does anyone know a way?

Regards.

Comment: https://medium.com/xcblog/wwdc18-a-basic-guide-to-app-store-connect-api-366208651ac6 ; https://github.com/topics/itunesconnect ;

Comment: is that working already? It seems to me that it doesn't